# Can the artemis-jms-client talk to an IBM MQ?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, activemq-artemis

I am currently tasked with sending data from a Java application to an IBM Message Queue.

My understanding is that the IBM MQ implements the JMS spec and I therefore can talk to it using the [artemis-jms-client](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/artemis-jms-client) since it also implements the JMS spec.

Is this correct? Or do I need an IBM specific client?

I was hoping to use ActiveMQ in testing since I cannot use the IBM MQ for this purpose.

Comment: JMS is API specification, not a protocol specification. JMS implementations differ from vendor to vendor due to proprietary wire level protocols used. Hence artemis-jms-client will not work with IBM MQ. You will need IBM MQ JMS client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, it won't work but your code shouldn't be vendor specific (since it would only use the JMS API) and thus should be portable to IBM MQ once the proper classpath is set.